# Why doesn't my removeClass() and addClass() function work?

Tags: jquery

My icon does not change when I click the icon. addClass and removeClass are not working. I used Font Awesome icons for reaction process.

jQuery functions are not working but the data is inserted to the database. Just the icon changes. I don't know why. Please help me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // when the user clicks the like button
  $('.like-btn').on('click', function() {
    var post_id = $(this).data('id');

    $clicked_btn = $(this);

    if ($clicked_btn.hasClass('fa-regular fa-heart')) {
      action = 'like'
    } else if ($clicked_btn.hasClass('fa-solid fa-heart fa-beat')) {
      action = 'unlike';
    }

    $.ajax({
      url: 'user_detail.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: {
        'action': action,
        'post_id': post_id
      },

      success: function(data) {
        res = JSON.parse(data);
        
        if (action == 'like') {
          $clicked_btn.removeClass('fa-regular fa-heart');
          $clicked_btn.addClass('fa-solid fa-heart fa-beat');
        } else if (action == 'unlike') {
          $clicked_btn.removeClass('fa-solid fa-heart fa-beat');
          $clicked_btn.addClass('fa-regular fa-heart');
        }
        
        $clicked_btn.siblings('span.likes').text(res.likes)
      }
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: We need to see more code. like where is `$clicked_btn` defined and where do you get `action` from

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. There's not enough information here to help. Also, you might set your browser to check spelling of your English. You had very many mistakes.